# TCP socket 'deleted' every 6 minutes on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, server

We have to migrate a System with our software from a Windows Server 2003 to a Windows Server 2012 R2. At this project we just changed the server hardware (to a HP ProLiant Server), the OS and the ISDN card with the CAPI driver. On this server there is a C++ application which filters a 30 byte character string out of the ISDN D-Channel and send it over a TCP socket (localhost, port 30000) to a JAVA application. The message comes every 30 seconds and has always the same format.

The problem is: Every 6 minutes the TCP socket is getting deleted/cleared/doesn't work. Both applications log the broken communication in their log files, build and open the socket again and the game goes on without any problems for another 6 minutes.

At the old system, this software works for years without any problems on Windows Server 2003 on 9 sites.

What we've already done without any positive effect:

- deactivate the firewall completely
- change the port to different ones (30001, 30500, 16000, 997)
- use the own IP (10.16.58.30) instead on localhost
- put several timeouts to the TCP Parameters at the registry (e.g. KeepAliveTime)
- update JAVA to the last version
- install all recommended updates for Windows Server 2012 R2
- strip both applications down to just the socket to ensure that the software itself hasn’t any problem
- using a standard message ('1234567891234567890') instead of the incoming ISDN message to exclude malfunction from strange input data
- checking the message length to exclude a length of 0
- checking all buffers on both sides to exclude buffer overflow
- checking if any other software on the server is using 'our' port

The problem doesn't appear, if we're sending the messages from outside manual or in different message cycles with a bash script to the server port of the JAVA app.

We are now thinking that this can only be some kind of checking mechanism of the operating system that forces our socket to stop communication. Any suggestions, what that could be?

Comment: Define 'deleted/cleared/doesn't work'. You've provided everything but the actual information required.

Comment: That's the point - I don't know. The low level sending function (send()) on the C++ app tells me a WSA Error 10054 "Connection closed by peer", the receive function on the JAVA application (socket.read()) tells me "software caused connection abort: recv failed". Both process IDs staying the same, means the apps itself are still working. I don't know, what exactly happens with the socket.

Comment: WSA 10054 is not 'connection closed by peer'. Look again. It is impossible to help you if you won't report the errors you get accurately and completely.

Comment: OK, EJB - it IS a 10054 WSA Error, and the correct wording seems to be "connection RESET by peer" (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - mea maxima culpa. The peer in this case is the same host, so the machine doesn't reboot or shut down, and the peer application is the JAVA application - and it doesn't reboot or shut down as well, 'cause the process ID is still the same.

Comment: @needmorecoffee May be [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2014/08/20/winsock-server-application-not-accepting-new-connections.aspx) is your problem as it was in my case.

Comment: @ja_mesa 's pointer to the kb article solved our problem too. We were able to apply the hot fix published there on a Windows Server 2012 R2 successfully with the expected results. Thanks a lot.